# Trigger JQuery function based on value of variable

Tags: php, jquery

I have a page that receives incoming values from $_POST.  One such value is from a drop down selector that allowed the user to select values 0 -10.  I want to trigger a JQuery function if a value greater than 0 was selected.

So, if $_POST['DropDownSelection'] > 0, then my JQuery function should run.

How do I trigger the function?

Comment: can we see that function??

Comment: if ($_POST['DropDownSelection'] > 0){ 
echo "jQuery(function(){ console.log('yo'))};"
}

Comment: @Misters: I don't think the function that is triggered is relevant. I know the function works because I currently have it tied to an onclick event.  However, I want to also call that function when the user lands on the page with a particular $_POST value for a field.

Comment: @john Smith:  that prints the jQuery call on the screen, but doesn't actually run the function.  Am I doing something wrong?  if(($otherscount) > 0) {
                                                                                         echo "jQuery(function(){ console.log('yo'))};";
                                                                                     }

Comment: i think this is "self-executing" when its parsed by the js-intepreter, of course it must be in script tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something i like to do for passing a PHP var to Javascript is to put in in an hidden input like that :

```
<input id="myValue" type="hidden" value="<?= $_POST['DropDownSelection']; ?>" />
```

The in your javascript :

```
if(document.getElementById('myValue').value > 0) //Do something
```

Answer (score 2):

If the function needs to be called in the original page then you can do this -

```
$('select[name="DropDownSelection"]').change(function() {
    var newValue = $(this).val();
    if(newValue > 0) {
        // your function here
    }
});
```

You don't need PHP, you just need to see if the value changed and then if the value is greater than 0.

If the function is in the page that gets posted to then you could do this -

```
<script>
    var DropDownSelection = <?php echo $_POST['DropDownSelection']; ?>;
    if(DropDownSelection > 0) {
        // call your function here
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The OP stated that the variable comes via POST from a drop-down on the _previous_ page, so this won't work. They need to somehow read and interpret the value from the POST header, and PHP is the simplest way to do this (and also the method the OP hinted at by using PHP's `$_POST[]` notation).

Comment: He stated that the value came from the dropdown and then was posted. You can complete the call to another set of functions without having to use the POST to verify the value has changed via PHP.

Comment: I suppose it's down to interpretation. When I read "a page that receives incoming values from $_POST" I didn't feel it was right to make the assumption that the OP was talking about a single page.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how your PHP code is connected to the HTML output. In the simplest case where PHP and HTML are in the same file, you could do something like

```
<? if ($_POST['DropDownSelection'] > 0) { ?>
<script>$.myFunction(...);</script>
<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that.

```
var x = <?php echo  $_POST['DropDownSelection'] ?>;
if(x>0){
  jqueryFunction(); // your function call. 
}else{
     // whatever else you want. 
}
```

Comment: Make sure you guard against `$_POST['DropDownSelection']` being non-numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is oversimplified and a little hacky, but I don't see why this wouldn't work...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function overZero() {
    // do stuff...
}

<?php
if ($_POST['DropDownSelection']>0) echo('overZero();');
?>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#dropdown-id").change(function(){
         //check if the value is > 0 and then
         // trigger your jquery function()
       })
    })
```

Comment: I don't want to trigger the event based on an action by the user.  I'd like to trigger the event based on a value from $_POST that I'm storing in a variable.

Comment: what triggers the $_POST to fill the dropdown ?

Answer (score 0):

**However, I want to also call that function when the user lands on the page with
     a particular $_POST value for a field**

There are 2 easy ways of doing this:

Make global funciton:

ex:

```
function print(){
alert('hello')
}



<?php
if($_POST['DropDownSelection'] != 0)
{
echo "<script>print()</script>";
}
?>
```

Or use [triger function](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) from jquery:

```
  <?php
    if($_POST['DropDownSelection'] != 0)
    {
    echo "<script>$('#dropdown').trigger('change');</script>";// execute the onchange event(function) attached to the dropdown
    }
?>
```